# Rspec test in ruby on rails, cannot load such file webmock/rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rspec2, rspec-rails

when I run rspec test in my ruby on rails application..

```
git@ruby-rails:~/gitlab$ sudo bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/public_spec.rb 
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/gollum-5dcd3c8c8f68/lib/gollum/markup.rb:222: warning: already initialized constant PREFORMATTED_TAGS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/gollum-5dcd3c8c8f68/lib/gollum/markup.rb:685: warning: already initialized constant MarkupGFM
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/gollum-5dcd3c8c8f68/lib/gollum/sanitization.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant ELEMENTS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/gollum-5dcd3c8c8f68/lib/gollum/sanitization.rb:23: warning: already initialized constant ATTRIBUTES
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/gollum-5dcd3c8c8f68/lib/gollum/sanitization.rb:46: warning: already initialized constant PROTOCOLS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/gollum-5dcd3c8c8f68/lib/gollum/sanitization.rb:52: warning: already initialized constant ADD_ATTRIBUTES
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/gollum-5dcd3c8c8f68/lib/gollum/sanitization.rb:62: warning: already initialized constant REMOVE_CONTENTS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/gollum-5dcd3c8c8f68/lib/gollum/sanitization.rb:68: warning: already initialized constant TRANSFORMERS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/gollum-5dcd3c8c8f68/lib/gollum/web_sequence_diagram.rb:7: warning: already initialized constant WSD_URL
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/gollum-5dcd3c8c8f68/lib/gollum.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:8:in `<module:Unit>'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:12:in `<module:ActiveSupport>'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:34:in `inherited'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:34:in `inherited'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:34:in `inherited'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:34:in `inherited'
MiniTest::Unit::TestCase is now Minitest::Test. From /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:34:in `inherited'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/backports-3.3.3/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require': cannot load such file -- webmock/rspec (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/backports-3.3.3/lib/backports/tools.rb:328:in `require_with_backports'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/git/gitlab/spec/spec_helper.rb:18:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc2/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
    from /home/git/gitlab/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/git/gitlab/spec/controllers/public_spec.rb:2:in `require'
    from /home/git/gitlab/spec/controllers/public_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:77:in `rescue in run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /home/git/gitlab/coverage. 2055 / 5187 LOC (39.62%) covered.
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
  gem 'coveralls', require: false
  gem 'rails-dev-tweaks'
  gem 'spinach-rails', '0.2.0'
  gem "rspec-rails", '2.12.2'
  gem "capybara", '2.0.2'
  gem "pry"
  gem "awesome_print"
  gem "database_cleaner"
--
  # Generate Fake data
  gem "ffaker"

  # Guard
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spinach'

  # Notification
  gem 'rb-fsevent', require: darwin_only('rb-fsevent')
```

I am sure that my Gemfile do contains rspec-rails. And this command also works fine:

```
ruby -e 'require "webmock/rspec"'
```

I doubt that there is something wrong with my bundler.

But when I check my bundle.

```
more /usr/local/bin/bundle
```

I saw:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

This means bundle is using the same ruby as I test.

Here is the ruby version I am using:

```
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

put this line in your GemFile

```
gem 'webmock'
```

and then do bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `gem 'webmock'`. See its wiki.